# Error "Repository is unrelated" when pushing repository with sub-repository to bitbucket

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

There is repository (GameFramework) which I want to use as sub repository in another repositories.

I created a new main repository and then clone GameFramework into this repository and make GameFramework a sub repository. But when I'm trying to push main repository to bitbucket I'm getting error: `repository is unrelated` or `repository is unrelated (in subrepo [path])`

This is strange but when after error I clear bitbucket repository and then push again it works!

I taked the video https://youtu.be/WI86_3I2ZH0

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change .hgsub file.
By default this file has the next format:

```
[folder to sub repo] = [folder to sub repo]
```

You need to chane it on:

```
[folder to sub repo] = [sub repo url]
```

Answer (score 2):

Two repositories are considered unrelated by mercurial, if they do not have the same origin, thus were created independently.

Without the use of the `--force` option mercurial does not allow pushing to unrelated repositories.

In your case, you (or someone else) likely created a repository for the sub-project in each of the projects separately and independently - and not referencing the same repository as sub-repository.

Fixing the issue is a bit tricky. Likely the easiest approach is to change to one of the sub-repos. Pull from the other sub-repo and do a merge as needed. And also doing it the other way around.

Comment: If the second repository is cloned from first, then these repositories are related or unrelated?

Comment: What do you mean by the same origin? It looks like I can create sub repository only when I created it from main repository. Is there way to check whether repositories are related or not?

Comment: A clone is always related to the repo it was cloned from (and vice versa): they have a common commit history.
However, you checked it already: they're not related... you can also compare the commit history / hashes in the repos (was one of the repos hist-edited?). But about creating sub-repos: a sub-repo is a totally ordinary repo which needs no special way of creation. Just tell the "main" repo that it has a sub-repo (and where), and that's it. Creating a completely new repo for the sub-repo for that reason is probably what caused the mess.

Comment: I'm pushing main repository to bitbucket empty repository and i'm getting error. Then in bitbucket I do strip to make repository empty again. And now I'm pushing to bitbucket again and it works. I repeated it a few times. wtf?